# How to set the URI to install a self-written trigger in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: triggers, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I wrote a trigger to be used in Apache IoTDB, but when I try to create it in IoTDB, I have to write a URI to install it. I tried `http://jar/aesc-iotdb-stream.jar`, but seems like the trigger is not successfully installed. What should be written in this URI to install a self-written trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default loading path of trigger in Apache IoTDB is `trigger_lib_dir=ext/trigger`, so you can install your trigger here. Remember to add `file:///` when using this local path.